# Minecraft keeps crashing after installing RPG texture package

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My friend tells me he installed the RPG texture package on Minecraft and every time he loads the client the game crashes with the standard Windows Error Report box.

<sub>I have not been able to replicate this error</sub>

Comment: What RPG texture package did your friend install? Could you post a screenshot of the Error Report / the Error report itself?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the bin folder, and reinstalling?

Comment: @Michael K The Eorror report message is like the standed Winodws has crashed. Please send/don't send the eorror report

Comment: Than again, what RPG texture package did he use? Had he tried to reinstall minecraft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He may not have applied the [HD texture fix](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=46173) required for some texture packs, or patched to a resolution still too low for that specific pack.

**update** Also (as in this case was the solution) an update will undo the patch so it has to be reapplied.

Comment: also, try that on a vanilla minecraft, I had a problem with an update _after_ having applied the HD fix first

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the problem is solved but here is to the people who still are having the issue:

Below this is a list of things that could be causing the problem, and below that is a list of fixes.

1. Not enough ram
2. Texturepack file is incorrect (meaning it is corrupted or configured incorrectly)
3. Needs to be patched

FIXES:

1. Not enough ram: Get a ram upgrade (get more information on RAM from here: http://bit.ly/18LBqFi)
2. Texturepack needs to be patched: Your texturepack is not configured correctly and needs to be patched. (MCPatcher: http://bit.ly/1jiuMet (Works 99% of the time) Optifine: http://bit.ly/1jOG2Di (Works 70% of the time, has zoom feature and increases frames))
3. Texturepack file is corrupt: Find new file.

I hope this helped!